# phpmyadmin mcrypt extension is missing

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, centos, mcrypt

I'm using CentOS 6 and the latest phpMyAdmin (4.0.1.4) and I noticed the error "The mcrypt extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration."

I went ahead and ran:

```
 rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

then ran:

```
yum install php-mycrypt
```

Then restarted httpd services and still no luck.

Any idea how I can get it to go away?

Comment: You can refer this [thread](http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=32954)

Answer (score 6):

According to [this post](http://www.sterndata.com/blog/phymyadmin-mcrypt-and-centos-6-mcrypt-extension-missing-solved), you should edit `/etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini` and change

```
; Enable mcrypt extension module
extension=module.so
```

to

```
; Enable mcrypt extension module
extension=mcrypt.so
```

and then restart.

Comment: Cheers, did the trick for me on CentOS 6.5 after yum -y php-mcrypt

Answer (score 4):

**On Ubuntu Try this for your mcrypt problem:**

```
mv -i /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for CentOS 6, but in case someone happens to have the **same problem for OSX lion/mountain lion**, [here is a solution](http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-development-server/)

Basically they make you (re)install `libmcrypt` and the latest version of php, and if you don't have it, `autoconf`.

Just follow the tutorial, it should work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS, Yum did not work for me. I downloaded and installed libmcrypt-***.tar.gz. See similar instruction in this link.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php.

Answer (score 0):

## Mac OS X Yosemite

> **the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system**

I fixed this error by running the following commands in my Terminal :

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap josegonzalez/homebrew-php
brew install php54-mcrypt
```