# PHP doesn't load mcrypt extension

Tags: php, nginx, centos, mcrypt

I can't see mcrypt in phpinfo() in section "Additional .ini files parsed". 'php_mcrypt' have been installed. I use CentOs with nginx with PHP 5.3.3.

In /etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini I wrote *extension=mcrypt.so*.

I tried to change the extension path in php.ini (ex *extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so*), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: in your phpinfo(), what value do you have in the "Scan for additional .ini files" field?

Comment: I see this path: /etc/php.d

Comment: just stupid questions, but: 1) does the mcrypt.so file exists and is in the right path? 2) did you restart nginx after your changes to ini files?

Comment: hehe, of course mcrypt.so file exists and I restarted nginx after every change :)

Comment: someone else here in SO had a similar problem in CentOS, and he installed mcrypt from sources, maybe this could work for you as well? http://stackoverflow.com/a/20552188/636348 (remove yum version before)

Comment: Resolved. Stupid thing. There was _; default extension directory.
extension =mcrypt.so;_ in php.ini (no colon to the begining of this line). So I commented it in php.ini and changes /etc/php.d/mcrypt.ini to **extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/mcrypt.so**. It works!
Thank you @LorenzoMarcon :)

Answer (score 3):

You are using Nginx, so i assume you are using php-fpm? 
If so you need to restart the php-fpm service in order to reload the plugins.

Restarting the nginx wont reload the php.ini